# How to deploy NUXT3 on Plesk using Phusion Passenger

Tags: node.js, passenger, plesk, phusion, nuxt3

I'm trying to deploy a Nuxt 3 website on Plesk, compiled with yarn build. I therefore have the PUBLIC and SERVER folders, which I have on Plesk hosting.

I have the server.js file which is the following:

`const app = require('./.output/server/index.mjs');
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT);`

I can't find a single guide for Nuxt 3, I need to start the application. From my understanding though, Phusion should start processes without launching a manual start command?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem, and it is way easier than I anticipated: What you need to do is simply create a server.js file, containing 1 line:

```
import('./server/index.mjs');
```

which is the file generated by nuxt3 in ./output/server/index.mjs.

That's all. I was definitely overcomplicating it coming from nuxt2, I hope it can save time to others.

Comment: Hi @Marghen, did you have any problems with Phusion Passenger crashing your nuxt3 app randomly? It is happening to me and I am clueless maybe you have encountered same problem :)

Comment: Hi @iSnuff, no I'm sorry, it didn't happen to me yet (fortunately). I don't know if it helps, but we've had some troubles with Phusion Passenger and nuxt 3 in the past and if I recall correctly the problem was a misconfiguration of the nuxt3 app on https. I'm not exactly sure what it was but adding some advanced configuration in nuxt.config made everything work great. What Node version are you setting up Nuxt with?

Comment: I am trying for hours now and can't get it working. Maybe you could help me? What is your `document root` and `application root`? Why do you create a server.js file instead of pointing the `application startup file` directly to `.output/server/index.mjs`?`Have you tried to do so?

Comment: @Marghen Thank you for this usefully hint! Did you find a way to generate this additional file within the "nuxt build" command? In my case every build deletes the former created server.js, which makes a deployment unnecessary complicated.

Comment: Hey there @AlexanderGrein,  no I did not, but I would simply automate the creation of the file upon deploying. What are you using? Something like vercel?

Comment: @aProgger I'm sorry for the late response, did you make it eventually?

Comment: Yes. I wrote an answer. Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you solved it

Comment: @Marghen, no, not vercel. I use a tool written in go (https://github.com/webdevops/go-sync). Anyway, I found a way: added this script config to my package.json "build": "nuxt build && cp ./server.js .output"

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is fine I guess but unfortunately was not the solution for me. I have a Plesk Obsidian with Phusion Passenger as the OP. Unfortunately I have no access to the logs and asking the provider is a pain in the ass.

My Plesk nodejs config looks like:

[image]

My app runs in a subdomain `abc.my-url.de`

So my `Document Root` is `abc.my-url.de/.output/public`
My `Aplication Url` is `http://abc.my-url.de`
My `Application Root` is `abc.my-url.de`

The `.output` dir is generated with `yarn build`

For the first time I advise you to set the `Application Mode` to `development` because Phusion Passenger doesn't tell you about errors otherwise.

And here is what makes the app running in my case:
I had to create a `app.cjs` (the name doesn't matter but the ending does) with the content:

```js
// !!! the ./ at the beginning is extremely important !!!
import('./.output/server/index.mjs');
```

My `Application Startup File` is `app.cjs` and is placed in the root of the subdomain where also the `.output` folder is generated.

If your app is running, don't forget to change the `Application Mode` to `production`.

---

The reason why I have to use a `cjs` file is not clear to me, because I do not know the nodejs settings of the provider and he is keeping it as a secret.

And the reason why I have to add the `./` to the import path inside the app.cjs is (so I was told from the provider) because Phusion Passenger copies the app into a sandboxed folder where it then runs. This doesn't explains it well but it's all I got.